# Likely concerns an interviewer will have about foreign candidate?

Tags: interviewing

In a nutshell, the title says it all.

I'm about to take several interviews for a position in a foreign country and I'd like to come to the interview as prepared as possible. As a someone from the foreign country, I believe one of the top concerns of the interviewer would be somehow related to the fact my homeland is on the other part of the continent.

Are there any particular things which I should address on interview to increase my chances of hiring or are there any questions which I should anticipate?

While I'd like an answer to be applicable for as many people in my situations as possible, if You'd like some context:

- my homeland is located in the south-east to central part of the Europe
- position I'm interviewed is in Ireland
- IT (software engineer) sector
- I'm in my middle to late 20's and holding bachelor's degree
- I'm not married and I don't have a kids; I'm in a relationship, however, as we are very young couple, I don't believe this will play much of a role on my decision
- I was scouted by hiring agencies

Comment: The title absolutely screams opinion-based, so obviously off-topic, but I'm not sure that's the question you're actually wanting to ask.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let me not address your specific situation (which we try not to do on this site), but address the more general question of what concerns an interviewer might have about a candidate from a foreign country.

1. **Visa issues.** This is going to be absolutely the number one concern. If the candidate needs a visa to work in my country, that's going to involve the company in extra expense, extra delay, extra complication.
2. **Qualification equivalency.** If the candidate was educated abroad, did that qualification train to the same standard as a local institution? How can I confirm that? There is a similar issue of experience equivalency.
3. **Work practices.** Is the candidate going to be familiar with the normal techniques and tools of the trade in my country?
4. **Language issues.**  Can the candidate communicate well enough in the local language?
5. **Cultural issues.** Is there a big difference in the way of working or communicating between the candidate's country and mine? Is that going to cause problems, or mean an adjustment period?
6. **Permenancy** Is the candidate likely to stick around here for the long term? Do they have ties elsewhere?

These will be more or less significant depending on the countries involved and the position.

Comment: Time zone issues - I was working in the US for an Irish company and the time differences made interacting with them very difficult.

Comment: The questioner says he is interviewing for a position *in a foreign country*.